# I am a twin who celebrated my 13th birthday on Friday the 13th. Is this rare? What is the probability of this occurring?

Tags: probability, calendar-computations

I was born a twin who celebrated my 13th birthday on Friday the 13th many years ago.  Is this rare?  What is the probability of this occurring?  I am a senior who finally wants to know the answer.  Can you help?  I realize it is quite common for a single birth, but for twins born 60+ years ago?  So much to consider in solving this.  I am afraid it is beyond my math skill level.  Thanks for your consideration   James

Comment: https://www.timeanddate.com/calendar/weekday-friday-13?ext=1  may help that and knowing the calendar repeats will help.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the probability of your 13th birthday being on a Friday is 1 in 7.

The probability of being born and the 13th is 12 in 365$\frac 14$.

So the probability of one's 13th birthday on Friday the 13th is $\frac 17*\frac {12}{365\frac 14} = \frac {16}{3409}$

The probability of your being a twin is... I have no idea.

Comment: Your formula for the number of Friday the 13th's in a year is not unreasonable, and (+1) for a brave try. But the _actual_ number can apparently vary from one to three per year in unexpected (to me anyhow) patterns.. See the [_Wikipedia article_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friday_the_13th) for details.

Comment: I never said anything about how many Friday the 13s are in a year and I did not give any such formula at all and no-one asked anything about how many Friday the 13ths exist in a year. Knowing how many exist in any specific year would be completely irrelevant to any probability involving unspecified years.

Comment: I meant "The probability of being born and the 13th is 12 in 365$\frac 14$" is not exactly true.

Comment: There are $7*28=196$ possible date/days combinations for dates under 39 an in a given year there are $12*28=336$ times for them to occur in a given.  Obviously they do not occur equally distributed in a single year because $7$ does not divide $12$. However over all years they are.

Comment: "I meant "The probability of being born and the 13th is 12 in 365 1/4" is not exactly true."  Not by the arguments you gave.  It is probably true that births are not universally distributed over possibilities.  but we assume they are, and if we ignore years divisible by 100 and not by 400 then, yes, the probability of being born on the 13th is 12 in 365 1/4 *is* exactly true.  It has nothing to do with how many Fri the 13ths there are in a *specific* year (which is completely determined by what day Jan. 1 is.. which has 7 equally likely options.)

Comment: There are $28=4*7$ years or $28*365 + 7 =10277$ days in a complete calendar cycle.  There are $48$ of each X-day the $k$th for $k \le 28$.  This accounts for $48*28*7=9408$ of this days.  There are $45$ X-day the 29th. and $44$ X-day the 30th.  and $28$ X-day the 31st.  This accounts for all 10277 possible day dates combinations.  The probability of Friday the 13 is $\frac {48}{10277}= \frac 17*\frac {12}{365 \frac 14}$.  That *is* exact (assuming births are equally probable to occur on any possible date).

Comment: In short there are 48 Friday the thirteenths between Jan. 1, 2001 and Dec. 31, 2028.   Or in any 28 year period between March 1. 1900 and Feb. 28, 2100.

Comment: That *averages* to $1 \frac 57$ Friday the 13ths a year.  That is consistant with a probability of $\frac 17*\frac {12}{365 \frac 14}$.  If we had been told the OP was born in 1942 the probability of a 13th bday on fri13 is 1/366.   But if we had been told the OP was born in 1943 the prob is 3/365.  I suppose that since s/he said 60+ i should assum 1937-1946 which means the prob is not exactly 48/10277 but 19/3653.

Comment: @fleablood "There are 10277 days in a complete calendar cycle" is incorrect as this doesn't take into account leap years correctly, choosing to only look at the "once every four years is a leap year" rule ignoring the rest "unless the year is divisible by 100 and not by 400."  There are in fact 146097 days in a complete calendar cycle and day of the week is not perfectly independent from day of the month.

Comment: I mentioned the 100 and not 400 in an earlier comment and mentioned that this only applies to dates between March 1. 1900 and Feb. 28, 2100.  I'm not sure what you consider to be a 146097 day cycle.  I figure if we take the 100 year into account a cycle will be $7*400 =2800$ years.... Oh.. I think I see what you are saying.  3/1/1900 is Thurs and 3/1,2072 is Sun.  So Thurs to Sun occur one time more frequently than Mon-Wed.  But since we can assume everything has occurred between within a human lifetime of the present.  I don't think that matters.

Answer (score 0):

There are many factors, and depending on what factors you deem to be important this will affect the answer.

For simplicity's sake, we can probably safely assume that the date of birth is independent of whether or not you were born a twin.  Further, we can probably safely assume that each day in the calendar is equally likely to be a randomly selected person's birthday.  Finally, we should probably ignore child mortality rates and assume that death rates are independent of date of birth and being a twin.

> In a bizarre alternate world where all twins are sacrificed according to some religious ritual by their tenth birthday, the probability that a twin would celebrate their thirteenth birthday on friday the thirteenth would of course be zero.  This is an extreme example of when if deathrates are not in fact independent, we could have skewed results.  We don't technically know if they are independent, but I see no reason to believe otherwise or that it would otherwise significantly affect the results.

Many sources cite that about 32 people out of every 1000 is a twin.

As discussed in my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1496078/probability-13th-birthday-occurs-on-friday-the-13th), if we assume all days in the calendar are equally likely birthdays, chance of having 13th birthday on friday 13th is the same chance as having been born on a friday the 13th.  Our calendar repeats and friday the thirteenths do occur at a slightly above average rate at exactly $688$ occurrences out of $146097$ days (*the length of time until the calendar repeats again*).

Given our assumptions then, the probability that a randomly selected person happens to be a twin who celebrated their thirteenth birthday on friday the thirteenth is approximately

$\frac{32}{1000}\cdot\frac{688}{146097}\approx 0.00015069$, or about one in $6635$ people.

Compare this to the more naive calculation $\frac{32}{1000}\cdot\frac{1}{7}\cdot\frac{12}{365.2425}\approx 0.00015019$ where we incorrectly assume day of the week is independent of day of month.  It is ever so slightly less, but still a close approximation.  As a further comparison, about one in 212 people have their thirteenth birthdays on a friday the thirteenth.

> In reality, the assumption that every calendar date is equally likely is probably not valid, but it allows us to do our calculations.  There are generally more births during the fall.  The exact amounts though are relatively close, and there is a thirteenth of the month in every month, so the true figures should not vary from the above results by any significant amount.